# How can I read a text file of dates and convert them into an array that I can sort in C#?

Tags: c#, sorting, date, datetime

I have a text file of dates that appear like this:

```
16/02/2015
13/02/2015
12/02/2015
11/02/2015
10/02/2015
09/02/2015
```

and so on.

How can I convert this into something that I can use in a quick sort for example?
I am already reading the text file like this

```
string[] Date = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("Date.txt");
```

I've tried using something like this:

```
double[] Dates = Array.ConvertAll(Date, s => DateTime.Parse(s));
```

And this just doesn't work.

My desired output after being put through my algorithm is to have them in order but outputting the same format as I have showed previously.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for reading.

## EDIT

So I have managed to get the dates outputting in the way that I desire using this method:

```
string[] Date = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("Date.txt");
DateTime[] Dates = Array.ConvertAll(Date, s => DateTime.Parse(s));
```

However, it is also outputting a time.

```
19/01/2014 00:00:00
```

How can I get rid of this?

Thanks again, guys!

Comment: `DateTime` is a separate type to `double`.  Have a array of `DateTime` instead.

Comment: Please check my updated comment, It might help you

Comment: for your edit: Use DateTime.ToShortDateString() as described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 4):

[DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) takes a string and format to parse into a DateTime objects.

Using linq...

```
dates.Select(p=> DateTime.ParseExact(p, @"dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Should return a collection of dates you can then sort.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below snippet,

```
 string[] Dates = File.ReadAllLines("Date.txt");
            var sortableDates = Dates
                .Select<string, DateTime>(d => DateTime.ParseExact(d, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                .ToArray<DateTime>();
```

Updated Answer as per Edited question,

```
var sortableDates = File.ReadAllLines("Date.txt")
                .Select<string, DateTime>(d => DateTime.ParseExact(d, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                .OrderBy<DateTime, DateTime>(d => d)
                .Select<DateTime, string>(d => d.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
                .ToArray<string>();
```

Answer as per users implementation,

```
var result = Array.ConvertAll<string, DateTime>(Dates, d => DateTime.ParseExact(d, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                 .OrderBy<DateTime, DateTime>(d => d)
                 .Select<DateTime, string>(d => d.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
                 .ToArray<string>();
```

Comment: I have kept Format specific to "dd/MM/yyyy", because I thought user might be interested in this specific format only. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can entirely avoid the issue of converting to a date doing it this way:

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("Date.txt")
    .OrderBy(x => x.Substring(6, 4) + x.Substring(3, 2) + x.Substring(0, 2));
```

This only works because the data is uniform in each line.

Answer (score -1):

```
int ConvertDate(string date)
    {
        string day = "";
        string month = "";
        string year = "";
        int count = 0;

        foreach(char c in date)
        {
            if(count < 2)
                day = day + c;
            else if(count > 5)
                year = year + c;
            else if(c != '/')
                month = month + c;

            count++;
        }

        string tempDate = year + month + day;
        return Convert.ToInt32(tempDate);
    }
```

Comment: Assuming a particular format for dates is problematic (char 6 is a /), also you've missed the sort dates issue.